# Stir the pot, in American Spanish

Tags: modismos

What is the correct way to express this idiomatic expression?  -- Stir the pot --

My goal is to say something like "*she stirs the pot even more by inviting this person to her house.*"

I would imagine I could get away with saying something like,

> Ella complica la circumstancia más por invitar a esta persona a su casa.

but that doesn't sit well with me as a good translation.  In English, "stir the pot" has a distinct meaning and a distinct way of expressing the complications such that I wouldn't even have to mention the situation at all.

Comment: BTW, "por invitar" does not seem right to me here, I'd prefer "al invitar" or "invitando"

Comment: "revolver la olla" and "revolver el estofado" were quite common in Argentina, but not much used nowadays

Comment: Does that not literally mean to stir the pot though?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't know that idiom in English, but from what I see, there are some expressions that can fit. They have slightly different meanings:

- **[Echar leña al fuego](http://dle.rae.es/le%C3%B1a)**: do or say something to worsen a situation
- **Echar sal en la herida**: do or say something that increases somebody's pain (physical or emotional)
- **[Sacar los trapos sucios](http://dle.rae.es/trapo)**: make public someone else's faults
- **Revolver la mierda**: bring back an issue that is settled

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I have came to the conclusion after searching and searching and asking people I know that

> Empeorar la situación

is the closest I am going to get.  But for educations sake, feel free to provide more solutions.... If there is any way possible to avoid the word situación, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

In México I use this expression: “Ella trata de amarrar navajas al invitarlo(la) a su casa”.

And in a higly friendly informal way I would say: “Ella le echa limón a la herida al invitarlo(la) a su casa”.

Comment: By the way, is "stir the pot" a British expression?

Comment: That comment should probably belong on the question, not your answer.  But it is a somewhat common phrase in American English. I don't know if it's used in British English or not.

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurre:

Puso las cosas peor invitando a esa persona a su casa.

Ella puso las cosas todavía peor al invitarlo a su casa.

Ella lo complicó todo mas ...

Se acabó de complicar invitándolo a casa.